# How to delete div not having <a> tag from Multiple div with same classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am generation Multiple div but some div does not contain  tag. I want to delete such divs on button click event.

```
    <div class='small-4 large-4 columns'>
        <a class='notifications_star none' href='#' id='rank'></a>
    </div>
    <div class='small-4 large-4 columns'>
    </div>
    <div class='small-4 large-4 columns'>
        <a class='notifications_star none' href='#' id='rank'></a>
    </div>
```

how to delete 2nd div? I have many div like 2nd one and I want to delete it on Button click.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `not` method:

```
$('div.columns').not(':has(a)').remove();
```

Please note that IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use compound selector with `:not` and `:has`:

```
$("div:not(:has(*))").remove();
```

This will remove all `<div>` elements that do not contain any tag inside.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
$('div.columns').filter(function(){
     return !$(this).find('a').length;
}).remove();
```